# PyGObject, dbus python and metaclasses

Tags: python, dbus, pygobject, dbus-python

I want to subclass two python classes: one from PyGObject and one from python3-dbus:

```
import gi
from gi.repository import GObject
import dbus.service

class Test(GObject.Object, dbus.service.Object):
    pass
```

However I'm receiving following error:

```
$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ".../test.py", line 5, in <module>
       class Test(GObject.Object, dbus.service.Object):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I've already find out that it is because `GObject.Object` and `dbus.service.Object` have different metaclasses, and I need to do subclass them too:

```
class M_Test(gi.types.GObjectMeta, dbus.service.InterfaceType):
    pass

class Test(GObject.Object, dbus.service.Object):
    __metaclass__=M_Test
    pass
```

However it doesn't help, I continue to receive the same error. Maybe `gi.types.GObjectMeta` and `dbus.service.InterfaceType` is not correct metaclasses for `GObject.Object` and `dbus.service.Object`. Does anybody know how to do merge metaclasses of `GObject.Object` and `dbus.service.Object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3 changed syntax of specifying metaclasses. [PEP-3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/)

It's `class Test(GObject.Object, dbus.service.Object, metaclass=M_Test):` now.